# Python - Pandas library returns wrong column values after parsing a CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

- **SOLVED** Found the solution by myself. Turns out that when you want to retrieve specific columns by their names you should pass the names in the order they appear inside the csv (which is really stupid for a library that is intended to save some parsing time for a developer IMO). Correct me if I am wrong but i dont see a on option to get a specific columns values by its name if the columns are in a different order...

I am trying to read a comma separated value file with python and then 
parse it using Pandas library. Since the file has many values (columns) that are not needed I make a list of the column names i do need.

[Here's a look at the csv file format.](https://pastebin.com/R7LfqiFh)

> Div,Date,HomeTeam,AwayTeam,FTHG,FTAG,FTR,HTHG,HTAG,HTR,Attendance,Referee,HS,AS,HST,AST,HHW,AHW,HC,AC,HF,AF,HO,AO,HY,AY,HR,AR,HBP,ABP,GBH,GBD,GBA,IWH,IWD,IWA,LBH,LBD,LBA,SBH,SBD,SBA,WHH,WHD,WHA
>   E0,19/08/00,Charlton,Man City,4,0,H,2,0,H,20043,Rob
>   Harris,17,8,14,4,2,1,6,6,13,12,8,6,1,2,0,0,10,20,2,3,3.2,2.2,2.9,2.7,2.2,3.25,2.75,2.2,3.25,2.88,2.1,3.2,3.1
>   E0,19/08/00,Chelsea,West Ham,4,2,H,1,0,H,34914,Graham
>   Barber,17,12,10,5,1,0,7,7,19,14,2,3,1,2,0,0,10,20,1.47,3.4,5.2,1.6,3.2,4.2,1.5,3.4,6,1.5,3.6,6,1.44,3.6,6.5
>   E0,19/08/00,Coventry,Middlesbrough,1,3,A,1,1,D,20624,Barry
>   Knight,6,16,3,9,0,1,8,4,15,21,1,3,5,3,1,0,75,30,2.15,3,3,2.2,2.9,2.7,2.25,3.2,2.75,2.3,3.2,2.75,2.3,3.2,2.62
>   E0,19/08/00,Derby,Southampton,2,2,D,1,2,A,27223,Andy
>   D'Urso,6,13,4,6,0,0,5,8,11,13,0,2,1,1,0,0,10,10,2,3.1,3.2,1.8,3,3.5,2.2,3.25,2.75,2.05,3.2,3.2,2,3.2,3.2
>   E0,19/08/00,Leeds,Everton,2,0,H,2,0,H,40010,Dermot
>   Gallagher,17,12,8,6,0,0,6,4,21,20,6,1,1,3,0,0,10,30,1.65,3.3,4.3,1.55,3.3,4.5,1.55,3.5,5,1.57,3.6,5,1.61,3.5,4.5
>   E0,19/08/00,Leicester,Aston Villa,0,0,D,0,0,D,21455,Mike
>   Riley,5,5,4,3,0,0,5,4,12,12,1,4,2,3,0,0,20,30,2.15,3.1,2.9,2.3,2.9,2.5,2.35,3.2,2.6,2.25,3.25,2.75,2.4,3.25,2.5
>   E0,19/08/00,Liverpool,Bradford,1,0,H,0,0,D,44183,Paul
>   Durkin,16,3,10,2,0,0,6,1,8,8,5,0,1,1,0,0,10,10,1.25,4.1,7.2,1.25,4.3,8,1.35,4,8,1.36,4,8,1.33,4,8

This list is passed to pandas.read_csv()'s names parameter.
[See code.](https://pastebin.com/PQ1gsmsF)

```
# Returns an array of the column names needed for our raw data table

def cols_to_extract():
    cols_to_use = [None] * RawDataCols.COUNT

    cols_to_use[RawDataCols.DATE] = 'Date'
    cols_to_use[RawDataCols.HOME_TEAM] = 'HomeTeam'
    cols_to_use[RawDataCols.AWAY_TEAM] = 'AwayTeam'
    cols_to_use[RawDataCols.FTHG] = 'FTHG'
    cols_to_use[RawDataCols.HG] = 'HG'
    cols_to_use[RawDataCols.FTAG] = 'FTAG'
    cols_to_use[RawDataCols.AG] = 'AG'
    cols_to_use[RawDataCols.FTR] = 'FTR'
    cols_to_use[RawDataCols.RES] = 'Res'
    cols_to_use[RawDataCols.HTHG] = 'HTHG'
    cols_to_use[RawDataCols.HTAG] = 'HTAG'
    cols_to_use[RawDataCols.HTR] = 'HTR'
    cols_to_use[RawDataCols.ATTENDANCE] = 'Attendance'
    cols_to_use[RawDataCols.HS] = 'HS'
    cols_to_use[RawDataCols.AS] = 'AS'
    cols_to_use[RawDataCols.HST] = 'HST'
    cols_to_use[RawDataCols.AST] = 'AST'
    cols_to_use[RawDataCols.HHW] = 'HHW'
    cols_to_use[RawDataCols.AHW] = 'AHW'
    cols_to_use[RawDataCols.HC] = 'HC'
    cols_to_use[RawDataCols.AC] = 'AC'
    cols_to_use[RawDataCols.HF] = 'HF'
    cols_to_use[RawDataCols.AF] = 'AF'
    cols_to_use[RawDataCols.HFKC] = 'HFKC'
    cols_to_use[RawDataCols.AFKC] = 'AFKC'
    cols_to_use[RawDataCols.HO] = 'HO'
    cols_to_use[RawDataCols.AO] = 'AO'
    cols_to_use[RawDataCols.HY] = 'HY'
    cols_to_use[RawDataCols.AY] = 'AY'
    cols_to_use[RawDataCols.HR] = 'HR'
    cols_to_use[RawDataCols.AR] = 'AR'

    return cols_to_use


# Extracts raw data from the raw data csv and populates the raw match data table in the database

def extract_raw_data(csv):
    # Clear the database table if it has any logs
    # if MatchRawData.objects.count != 0:
        # MatchRawData.objects.delete()

    cols_to_use = cols_to_extract()

    # Read and parse the csv file
    parsed_csv = pd.read_csv(csv, delimiter=',', names=cols_to_use, header=0)

    for col in cols_to_use:
        values = parsed_csv[col].values
        for val in values:
            print(str(col) + ' --------> ' + str(val))
```

Where RawDataCols is an IntEnum.

```
class RawDataCols(IntEnum):
    DATE = 0
    HOME_TEAM = 1
    AWAY_TEAM = 2
    FTHG = 3
    HG = 4
    FTAG = 5
    AG = 6
    FTR = 7
    RES = 8 
    ...
```

The column names are obtained using it. That part of code works ok. The correct column name is obtained but after trying to get its values using

```
 values = parsed_csv[col].values
```

pandas return the values of a wrong column. The wrong column index is around 13 indexes away from the one i am trying to get. What am i missing?

Comment: Can you please post a sample of the data and the code, the link is not accessible for me. It is adviced not to post images in questions.

Comment: @anky_91 sure! But that's not an image. Its a link to a pastebin which is a text storage site where users can store plain text which could be highlighted depending on a programming language. Will edit my post

Comment: sorry , i meant links. :)

Comment: Question has been edited. Thanks

Comment: please see how to create a [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, i am not able to reproduce the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can select column by name wise.Just use following line

```
values = parsed_csv[["Column Name","Column Name2"]]
```

Or you select Index wise by

```
cols = [1,2,3,4]
values = parsed_csv[parsed_csv.columns[cols]]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! That's what i do with the slight difference that I get the column names from an array. Tried hardcoding the column name as you did but the result is the same - gets a wrong column values. Then tried using integer indexes with the same result.

Comment: It must be encoding problem

Comment: I'm not sure. I think it might be some wrong configuration of the read_csv method parameters...